# GoLand get dependencies: Access is denied

Tags: go, goland

Source code https://github.com/donhuvy/golang-fiber-jwt-rs256 , Windows 11 x64, GoLand 2022.3.2

Environment

```golang
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>go version
go version go1.20.1 windows/amd64

C:\Users\donhu>go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\donhu\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\donhu\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.20.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=NUL
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2148013967=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches

C:\Users\donhu>
```

[image]

log

```
GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Program Files\Go;C:\Users\donhu\go #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" mod tidy #gosetup
go: downloading github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 v2.42.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.5.0
go: downloading github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.11.2
go: downloading github.com/redis/go-redis/v9 v9.0.2
go: downloading gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.4.6
go: downloading github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4 v4.4.3
go: downloading github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.4.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.6.0
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\philhofer: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\go-playground\locales\@v\v0.14.1.mod744868971.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\mattn\go-isatty\@v\v0.0.17.mod576006998.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\savsgio: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\go-playground\universal-translator\@v\v0.18.1.mod955650152.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\mattn\go-runewidth: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\jackc\pgx\v5\@v\v5.2.0.mod568647868.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\golang-jwt: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\redis: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\go-playground\validator\v10\@v\v10.11.2.mod837851353.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\mattn\go-colorable\@v\v0.1.13.mod953369410.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\gofiber\fiber\v2\@v\v2.42.0.mod371498182.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\rivo: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\cespare\xxhash\v2\@v\v2.2.0.mod537173617.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\satori: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\savsgio: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\valyala\fasthttp\@v\v1.44.0.mod18096356.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\tinylib: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\sys\@v\v0.4.0.mod863177765.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\crypto\@v\v0.5.0.mod312250002.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\text\@v\v0.6.0.mod354109860.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\gorm.io\driver\postgres\@v\v1.4.6.mod188212583.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\sys\@v\v0.0.0-20220811171246-fbc7d0a398ab.mod521936526.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\mattn\go-isatty\@v\v0.0.16.mod868973549.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\sys\@v\v0.0.0-20220728004956-3c1f35247d10.mod319712144.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\net\@v\v0.0.0-20220906165146-f3363e06e74c.mod456296739.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\tools\@v\v0.0.0-20201022035929-9cf592e881e9.mod642006042.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\sync\@v\v0.0.0-20220923202941-7f9b1623fab7.mod844694859.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\jackc\pgservicefile\@v\v0.0.0-20200714003250-2b9c44734f2b.mod280805063.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\text\@v\v0.3.8.mod88272299.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\crypto\@v\v0.0.0-20220829220503-c86fa9a7ed90.mod826046346.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\crypto\@v\v0.4.0.mod247782492.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\go.uber.org\atomic\@v\v1.10.0.mod697775226.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\net\@v\v0.3.0.mod700057923.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\sys\@v\v0.3.0.mod289877815.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\term\@v\v0.3.0.mod441082438.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\golang.org\x\text\@v\v0.5.0.mod950083791.tmp: Access is denied.
go: writing go.mod cache: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\jackc\puddle\v2\@v\v2.1.2.mod877707775.tmp: Access is denied.
go: github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal@v1.8.0: verifying go.mod: github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal@v1.8.0/go.mod: open C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\sumdb\sum.golang.org\latest: Access is denied.
```

[image]
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Set permission Edit for USER

[image]

result: it is ok
[image]